# Prophecy regarding conversion to Judaism

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets, messianic-redemption

I remember reading somewhere in the Tanakh (in one of the of the books from Nevi'im), that when the times of the Messiah are coming near, many gentiles will start to express an increase interest in Judaism and especially in converting to it.

1. It was some time a go and I don't remember exactly where I read this, can anyone provide an exact source ?
2. Is there any additional commentary which expounds on this subject in detail ?

Answer (score 4):

In answer to the first question it says clearly in [Yeshaya 2:2-3](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the following:

> וְהָיָ֣ה ׀ בְּאַחֲרִ֣ית הַיָּמִ֗ים נָכ֨וֹן יִֽהְיֶ֜ה הַ֤ר בֵּית־יְהוָה֙ בְּרֹ֣אשׁ הֶהָרִ֔ים וְנִשָּׂ֖א מִגְּבָע֑וֹת וְנָהֲר֥וּ אֵלָ֖יו כָּל־הַגּוֹיִֽם׃
>
> *In the days to come, The Mount of the LORD’s House Shall stand firm above the mountains And tower above the hills; And all the nations Shall gaze on it with joy.*
>
> וְֽהָלְכ֞וּ עַמִּ֣ים רַבִּ֗ים וְאָמְרוּ֙ לְכ֣וּ ׀ וְנַעֲלֶ֣ה אֶל־הַר־יְהוָ֗ה אֶל־בֵּית֙ אֱלֹהֵ֣י יַעֲקֹ֔ב וְיֹרֵ֙נוּ֙ מִדְּרָכָ֔יו וְנֵלְכָ֖ה בְּאֹרְחֹתָ֑יו כִּ֤י מִצִּיּוֹן֙ תֵּצֵ֣א תוֹרָ֔ה וּדְבַר־יְהוָ֖ה מִירוּשָׁלִָֽם׃
>
> *And the many peoples shall go and say: **“Come, Let us go up to the Mount of the LORD, To the House of the God of Jacob; That He may instruct us in His ways, And that we may walk in His paths.”** For instruction shall come forth from Zion, The word of the LORD from Jerusalem.*

Comment: Can you support your claim that this refers to "when the times of the Messiah are coming near"?

Comment: @msh210 the verses are famously regarded as a clear allusion to the coming of Moshiach - Ibn Ezra on the words **in the days to come** says expressly that this is a reference to Moshiach

Comment: (re your comment) Then it __doesn't__ refer to "when the times of the Messiah are coming near".

Answer (score 1):

After some remembering and searching, I have also found [Zechariah 8:23](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16212)

*So said the Lord of Hosts: **In those days**, when **ten men of all the languages of the nations** shall take hold of the skirt of a Jewish man, saying, **"Let us go with you, for we have heard that God is with you***."

The expression used is "In those days", but there is the same issue as in the verse from the previous answer, it is not clear whether this refers to the past or to the future.

In verse 9 ibid, appears the phrase "in these days" but according to Rashi this refers to the 4th year of Darius.

Are "in these days" and "In those days" different ?

Because the [Sefaria translation](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.8?lang=bi) says "now" regarding vv 9 and "In those days" regarding vv 23.

I am not sufficiently proficient in hebrew to discern the exact meaning.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I don't necessarily mind it, but an explanation would be helpful for me to improve the answer and for future reference.